# Perfomance of XSLT-includes vs XSLT-extesions with Java

Tags: java, xml, performance, xslt

I have a big XML file that lacks information, most of these data are codes and I need to generate a PDF file with the descriptions.

On the other hand, I have all descriptions needed accesible from my java application, the question is: **What of the following options is most fast?**

1. Using XSTL-extension for access to the information storaged in a Map
2. Using XSTL-extension for access to the information storaged in a local database
3. Using XSTL-include for read a file generated by my java process that contains variables with name=ids and Select=descriptions.

I'm worried about the performance because I'm talking about a lot of ids (data).

Comment: So, why don't you go ahead and measure the performance?

Comment: because, I don't have enough time, I'm looking for people with experience in the area.

Comment: You will not benefit of any answer, I think. Your question is very vague and the answers will be, too. The outcome depends on your Java code, the libraries you use, the XSLT code you apply, the input XML, your machine etc.

Comment: Thinking about your last comment, the question is so specific, "What of the following options is most fast?", maybe you have not experience with this, but it not means that the question is vague, Nowadays there are programing patterns that improve performances without to know nothing about our devices.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I'm afraid. Of course one of those methods will turn out to be the fastest among the three. But the only reliable (and also the most straightforward) way to find out is to actually test this and measure the time they take and the resources they consume. If you "don't have enough time for this", frankly, you should not think you are entitled to good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few time ago and I decided to use your third option:

Using XSTL-include for read a file generated by my java process that contains variables with name=ids and Select=descriptions.

because in this way yo can be indepedent of you core, not like with extensions.